# Missing type for additionalProperties in generated scala-play-server code

Tags: scala, playframework, openapi-generator

I was playing around with `openapi-generator`, and cant find a way to get it to generate valid scala code for `scala-play-server`.

I use the `petstore.json` I downloaded from [swagger.io](https://petstore.swagger.io/), and run
`openapi-generator generate -i petstore.json -g scala-play-server`

It seems to kinda work, *except*, the models it generates look like this:

```
case class Tag(
  id: Option[Long],
  name: Option[String]
  additionalProperties:
)
```

... which, of course, isn't valid scala code, and fails to compile.

I tried adding

```
--additional-properties=disallowAdditionalPropertiesIfNotPresent=false
```

to command line as some website I googled suggested, but that didn't make any difference (and neither did  changing `false` to `true`).

I guess, I could just put together a sed script, to run on all generated files and replace `additionalProperties:` with `additionalProperties: Map[String, Any]` (or just remove those lines completely - no idea why I would want them there), but thought I'd just ask first in case someone knows about an easy fix that wouldn't be this "hacky" ...

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, I am not a scala developer, but I spend a lot of time with the `open-api-generator`.

It appears this is a [known bug](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/13378) that was reported in September 2022.  However, it doesn't seem to have any comments or traction.  Feel free to add comments to the existing ticket.  Sometimes that helps them gain visibility.

I don't know if it matters, but I tested the other scala server generators, and all of them generate the class without the additional properties.  So, if you are able to use a different scala server generator, that may be a work around.

Another potential work around, if you don't ever plan to use the `additionalProperties` feature of OAS, would be to remove it from the mustache template.  You can do this [via templating](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/templating.md).  Copy the `caseClass.mustache` and the `model.mustache` templates into a directory of your choosing, and delete the references to the `additionalProperties`.  Then, add the template directory to your CLI generator via `-t/--template`.

I tried using the templating method myself and it works, however you will no longer be able to use the [`additionalProperties`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/dictionaries/) feature from OAS in your schema.

Comment: Yeah ... that _kinda_ works ... Except that there are also `*Impl.scala` files that need to be fixed, because they are trying to pass `Map.empty` into those model constructors :(

Comment: Nothing you can do about the `*impl.scala` file generation without creating your own custom generator.  Which, at that point you might as well open a PR on github.  Otherwise, just have to wait until the bug gets fixed.